# Common pattern with segues and table views in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uistoryboardsegue

I have the set up of a user clicking a UITableViewCell, this triggers a segue to a 'detail' view controller which is popped onto the stack.

First,

User Taps -> [myVC tableView didSelectRow...] - this is where I can work out which cell and therefore which model object my user wants to modify or access.

Second,

User Taps -> [myVC prepareForSegue...] - this is where I set up my detail view controller with the correct model object.

So, do I just store the selected model object in an instance variable between the two functions being called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `prepareForSegue`, the `sender` argument will be the cell, so you can work out which one was tapped at that point. You could also check the tableview's `selectedIndexPath` property.

You don't need to implement both functions.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you need to pass an instance of your model to your details view controller after you tap on a table view row. You have some ways to achieve that:

1. You can create a property in your view controller with a data type of your model. Let's name it for example `firstObject`. Then, inside `didSelectRow` you can set this property or update it according to your needs. Then, inside `prepareForSegue` you can pass this instance to your details view controller, by doing something like: `detailsVC.detailsObject = firstObject`.
2. Inside `prepareForSegue`, you can get the value of the current tapped table view row using `indexPathForSelectedRow.row`. Assuming that you have an array holding different objects of your model that you need them to be sent to your details view controller based on the tapped table view row index, you can do something like:
   `detailsVC.detailsObject = myObjectsArray[myTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row]`.

I hope that I was able to make it more clear for you.